# Question about a proof of the Fundamental Theorem of algebra

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Theorem: (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra): Given any positive integer
> $n \geq 1$ and any choice of complex numbers $a_0,a_1,..., a_n$, such
> that $a_n \neq 0$, the polynomial equation
>
> $(1) \quad a_n z_n +···+ a_1 z + a_0 = 0$
>
> has at least one solution $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Proof extract: For our argument, we rely on the fact that the function
> $|f(z)|=|a_n z^n+...+a_1 z+a_0|$ attains its minimum value. Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ be a point where the minimum is attained. We will show
> that if $f(z_0) \neq 0$, then $z_0$ is not a minimum, thus proving by
> contraposition that the minimum value of $|f(z)|$ is zero. Therefore,
> $f(z_0) = 0$. If $f(z_0) \neq 0$, then we can define a new function $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by setting
>
> $g(z)=\frac{f(z+z_0)}{f(z_0)}$, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
>
> Note that $g$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and that the minimum of
> $|f(z)|$ is attained at $z_0$ if and only if the minimum of $|g|$ is
> attained at $z = 0$. Moreover, it is clear that $g(0) = 1$. More
> explicitly, $g$ is given by a polynomial of the form
>
> $(2) \quad g(z)=b_n z^n+...+b_k z^k+1$
>
> with $n \geq 1$ and $b_k \neq 0$ for some $1 \leq k \leq n$. Let
> $b_k=|b_k| e^{i \theta}$, and consider $z$ of the form
>
> $(3) \quad z=r |b_k|^{-1/k} e^{i (\pi - \theta)/k}$,
>
> with $r>0$. For $z$ of this form we have
>
> $g(z)=1-r^k+r^{k+1} h(r)$
>
> where $h$ is a polynomial.

The rest of the proof is not relevant for my questions.

i) How do we know that $g(z)$ has the form given in $(2)$? We know that $g(0)=1$, so it is clear that the constant must be $1$. It is also clear that the highest power is $n$ since we basically rescale $f(z)$ by a factor of $f(z_0)$ after translating it by $z_0$. But why must $g$ have this specific form? What would go wrong if we would simply let $k=1$? I think the main point is that when doing this transformation from $f$ to $g$ some powers with non-zero coefficients $a_j$ might drop out, but this cannot happen for $a_n$.

ii) The text mentions $b_k=|b_k|e^{i \theta}$, which I think is simply the representation of the complex number $b_k$ using polar coordinates. Similarly, $(3)$ specifies a complex number $z$ by its polar coordinates. Is this understanding correct?

This is the last bit I need to understand to finally get an understanding why the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra is true.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: This proof is smarter. The proof which I know uses the difference $f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)$ instead of ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about ii).

To answer question i), notice the requirement $b_k \ne 0$, which might or might not be true for $k=1$. So, that form which is written is not a *specific* form of $n$th degree polynomial satisfying $g(0)=1$, it's actually equivalent equivalent to the *general* form. You would start from the general form $g(z) = b_n z^n + ... + b_1 z + 1$ and then you would set $k = \min\{ i \mid 1 \le i \le n, b_i \ne 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This confirms my understanding and the fact that $g$ must be a polynomial of the same degree as $f$ guarantees the existence of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

This is Argand's proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

(1) $n=k=1$ is allowed, in which case $g(z)$ takes the form $bz+1$, which has the solution $z=-1/b$. We know $g(z)$ has the given form because $g(0)=1$, so the constant term is 1, and $k$ is simply the exponent of the lowest non-zero term other than the constant term.

(2) Yes, you are correct for point (ii).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The proof makes $k$ look somehow special which is what confused me I think. But as you said it might well be that $g$ takes the form $g(z)=b_n z^n+...+b_1 z+1$ and in case we have $n=k$ as well we are in the case you mentioned, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This idea of letting $b_kz^k$ be the least non-zero term (or in this case, least non-constant non-zero term) is used elsewhere in algebra and analysis (and even number theory).